# Junit test not able to access the file system using LocalServiceTestHelper

Tags: java, unit-testing, google-app-engine, junit

I'm trying to access a static file under the /WEB-INF/ directory in Google App Engine project.

The following code works fine when running the dev server, but fails in a unit test.

```
String name = "WEB-INF/myfiles/myfile.dat";
File file = new File( name );
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream( file );
```

However the same code in a JUnit test throws a FileNotFoundException.

For what it's worth I have setup LocalServiceTestHelper so all datastore test cases work fine.

Is the unit testing running with a different working directory and if so, how can I set / correct this?

Comment: FileNotFoundException is pretty explanatory.  Your file path needs to be adjusted so that the test class can find the actual file.

Comment: There is no actual file in an unexploded war.

Comment: @SandySimonton the point is I can't adjust the path as the GAE won't find it, so I'm questioning how to adjust the junit runtime environment to mirror GAE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that it is related to LocalTestServiceHelper (which configures local implementation of AE services). The "current folder" that you are running the test does not have the "WEB-INF" folder there [originally or copied to]).

I am not sure how you run your unit-tests. Some IDEs will copy non-source folders to the "target" folder and in some cases you can configure your run script (ant build.xml, maven pom.xml, ...) to do such copying for you.

However though doable, as this is a unit-test you may want to consider
isolating the source loading part (which you can set differently for
tests and production) to the common logic that process that source which
you are testing.

Another option is to mock the input source (e.g. reading via ServletContext.getInputStream and mocking ServletContext to return
the content).

Comment: For anyone coming back to this, the solution was indeed in Eclipse run configuration - the directory had to be changed.